# Dnsmasq not working in port 53 but there's nothing else on port 53

Tags: raspbian, dnsmasq

So I'm running an apache2 server and hostapd on a raspberry pi 2, with raspbian. When I try to run dnsmasq with dnsmasq.conf localhost=127.0.0.1 (among others settings I don't think they are important now) it says

```
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use [fail].
```

But I have tried

```
lsof -i -P -n | grep '53'
```

and I only get `dnsmasq`.

When I run net `netstat -ap46` I get

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address State  PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql 0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 559/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:domain  0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 438/dnsmasq         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh     0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 445/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http       [::]:*          LISTEN 627/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 [::]:domain     [::]:*          LISTEN 438/dnsmasq         
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh        [::]:*          LISTEN 445/sshd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns    0.0.0.0:*              327/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:domain  0.0.0.0:*              438/dnsmasq         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc  0.0.0.0:*              370/dhcpcd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59990   0.0.0.0:*              327/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns       [::]:*                 327/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 [::]:55646      [::]:*                 327/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 [::]:domain     [::]:*                 438/dnsmasq         
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp  [::]:*             7   370/dhcpcd
```

I dont't have installed Network Manager.
Is dnsmasq interfering with itself? 
How can I fix it?

Comment: What does`netstat -ap46` say?  It lists the open sockets with their owning processes for the IPv4 and IPv6 protocols.  If port 53 is in use, I would expect it to be listed.

Comment: You'll have to edit your question to add the whole list in proper order. There should be an "edit" link at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Local Address, port 53 is named as :domain and listed as used by process "438/dnsmasq" for all the protocols. If you use `netstat -ap46n`, you will see the numbers instead of names.

The Program Name is dnsmasq, which means that it is already running indeed.  If you have `htop`, you can search for it by process id, which is 438 in this case.  It will show you the command that was used to start the process. Alternatively, use `cat /proc/438/cmdline` to display that information.

So with dnsmasq already running, you'll want to check the configuration file(s) and a hint towards which one is used can be found in the command as found in /proc/438/cmdline. The manpage for dnsmasq on my system does list a number of files, but not the directory `/etc/dnsmasq.d` and the default config file `/etc/default/dnsmasq`.  Checking the latter file may be a good place to start.  For example, use `sudo nano /etc/default/dnsmasq` to do it on the CLI.

I hope that's enough to get you going on this one.

Comment: Okay, so by checking all the configuration files and doing some research, I discovered that although you set `ENABLE=0` on `/etc/default/dnsmasq` in order to stop the daemon, you need to delete the `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` file or to run `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq stop` in order to stop the process. Thanks for the support